# Communication between java server and matlab client

Tags: java, sockets, matlab

I'd like to establish a server(Java)/client (Matlab) communication using socket. They can send messages to each other. An example shows how to do this in Java server and Java client, http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html.

When I try to rewrite the client part in Matlab, I only can get the first message that the Java server sends and display it in the Matlab command window.

When I type a message in the Matlab command window, I can't pass it to the Java Server.

Jave code:

```
kkSocket = new Socket("localhost", 3434);
```

Matlab equivalent:

```
kkSocket = Socket('localhost', 3434);
```

Java code for client:

```
    out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
```

What would be a Matlab equivalent for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the input stream:

```
input_stream   = input_socket.getInputStream;
d_input_stream = DataInputStream(input_stream);
```

For the output stream:

```
output_stream   = output_socket.getOutputStream;
d_output_stream = DataOutputStream(output_stream);
```

Comment: Thanks. I just replaced "output_socket" with input_socket.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use MATLAB and the Java application on the same machine then [matlabcontrol](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com) may do everything that you are looking for. It automatically establishes a connection to a session of MATLAB. It uses Java's [Remote Method Invocation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) under the hood which makes use of sockets. matlabcontrol is designed specifically to only enable communication on localhost; the sockets it creates will not accept remote connections due to the security issues that could allow. However, if you need to allow remote connections you may find parts of [matlabcontrol's source code](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/source/checkout) to be useful.